#  Can I cancel a vote for a comment?

Tags: support, comments, voting

I voted up for a comment and realized that it wasn't in fact such a great comment. I am not able to cancel my vote as I can do for questions or answers : "click again to undo" don't work.

Is it just impossible, is there some timeout impeding you to change your mind every 10s or is it a bug in my browser ?

I did not find an answer in the faq or the meta... Edit : should have looked on the other meta-sites.

Comment: Related to: [Does upvoting a comment add to the commenter's reputation? How much?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/637/does-upvoting-a-comment-add-to-the-commenters-reputation-how-much)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

[Cancelling upvote on comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment)

Comment: Thanks for the link ! Seems like a widely-wanted but low-priority feature... Was I right to post here ? The many meta-sites seem to duplicate some content.

Comment: I think it's appropriate to post it here, if anything to point people to the discussion on MSO; For new people the entire network layout and where to post can be confusing so they would post here anyway.

Comment: And of course some issues could be "askubuntu-specific", so I think its always better to ask here.

Comment: I up voted all your comments with no regrets!

Answer (score 6):

This feature was added.

But it is deliberately limited. To remove an upvote from a comment, you must not have left the page since casting the vote, and it must be within a minute of casting the vote.

Furthermore, once you've removed a comment vote, you cannot subsequent upvote the comment.

[**Source**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032/185080)